# Can I always assume the characters '0' to '9' appear sequentially in any C character encoding

Tags: c, character-encoding, c-strings

I'm writing a program in C that converts some strings to integers. The way I've implemeted this before is like so

```
int number = (character - '0');
```

This always works perfectly for me, but I started thinking, are there any systems using some obscure character encoding in which the characters '0' to '9' don't appear one after another in that order? This code assumes '1' follows '0', '2' follows '1' and so on, but is there ever a case when this is not true?

Comment: Baudot code had 1..9, then 0. That's one reason no one uses Baudot these days. ASCII, EBCDIC, and Unicode are fine.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: That, along with the lack of lowercase letters and some required punctuation characters, implies that a conforming C implementation can't use Baudot code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed by the C standard.

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.2.1 paragraph 3 says:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>   each character after **`0`** in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>   one greater than the value of the previous.

This guarantee was possible because both ASCII and EBCDIC happen to have this property.

Note that there's no corresponding guarantee for letters; in [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), the letters do not have contiguous codes.